# Resources/books/articles about estimation of $|f(z)|$

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables

I am new to complex analysis and I want to explore the following problem: for a complex valued  bounded function $f(z)$ in a domain, I would like to know how we estimate the modulus values in a given domain, especially when $f$ is a polynomial. I would be highly obliged if someone could kindly refer me to the relevant books/articles/papers.

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4369489/resources-books-articles-about-estimation-of-fz).